# Android: How does Application class work with remote processes?

Tags: android

Say that my app implements a subclass of `Application` has 2 different services running different processes.

What happens if I call `getApplication()` in each Service? Will I get back 2 completely independent instances, 1 for each process?

If so, then will the 2 instances be somehow linked? In other words, would modifications made to the instance in one process show up in the instance made in the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Say that my app implements a subclass of Application has 2 different services running different processes.

99.9999% of Android applications do not need this, and it wastes RAM, CPU, and battery.

> Will I get back 2 completely independent instances, 1 for each process?

Of course. They are different processes.

> If so, then will the 2 instances be somehow linked?

No.